# When add or remove item in view pager then scrolling should remain

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'd like to add item in ViewPager and allow the user to add or remove views as desired. When add or remove item in view pager then scrolling issue comes.when add item at 0 index then view pager should not be scroll down.

here is my code

```
private class StoryAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Item item = lists.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        final View viewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_story, container, false);
            TextView title =  viewItem.findViewById(R.id.titlestory);
         TextView storytext =  viewItem.findViewById(R.id.storytext);
        ImageView storyImg = viewItem.findViewById(R.id.storyimg);

        title.setTypeface(C.getBlackToBlackFont(getActivity()));
         storytext.setTypeface(C.getRobotoRegularFont(getActivity()));

        title.setText(item.storyTitle);
        storytext.setText(item.storyDescription);
        PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(getActivity()).load(item.storyImage).placeholder(R.drawable.dummyimage).error(R.drawable.dummyimage).fit().centerCrop().into(storyImg);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewItem);
        return viewItem;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lists.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return view == ((View) object);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
    }


}
```

XML:

```
<me.kaelaela.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager
    android:id="@+id/vertical_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hd"
    />
```

Comment: post your ViewPager  code  and xml

Comment: ok now i have added code